# Is there a way to export a piece of html or latex code as a pdf image?

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm generating a table with the library ztable, which needs to be exported as a pdf image. This code will be deposited in a computing cluster; therefore, rendering the plot with rmarkdown or in the viewer of R studio are not feasible options. The plot must be deposited in a pdf file.

```
library(ztable)
library(magrittr)
options(ztable.type="html") #or latex for latex output.
z=ztable(head(iris),caption="Table 1. Basic Table")
z
```

According to the ztable documentation, this piece of should render the plot in Rviewer and allow encapsulating it between a pdf('file.pdf')... dev.off() statement. However, it only prints in the console the html or latex code. I tried to use the latexpdf library with the following command `tex2pdf(z)`, but this simply returns an error `Error in file.exists(x) : invalid 'file' argument`.

Is there a way to redirect the output from html or latex an obtain the rendered table inside a pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `capture.output()` to get the printed latex output as an object, than write it to a LaTeX file with `cat()`, and finally you can create a pdf from the file:

```
library(ztable)
library(latexpdf)

options(ztable.type="latex") #or latex for latex output.

z <- ztable(head(iris),caption="Table 1. Basic Table")
cat(capture.output(z), sep = "\n", file = "tablez.tex")

tex2pdf("tablez.tex")
```

But note that the pdf output defaults to a full page, and you might have to change the defaults somehow or post-process the pdf futher:

[image: screenshot of tablez in pdf]

Comment: This solution doesn't work on MAC -> arguments 'show.output.on.console', 'minimized' and 'invisible' are for Windows only
sh: pdflatex: command not found

Comment: @je2018 I tested my solution on Linux, and would be surprised if it didn't work on Macs, as their OS is UNIX based. Do you have a LaTeX installation on your machine?